# Accessing JSON inside a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, prestashop

I am trying to get a particular part of an array and change it to HTML before sending it back to my view.

I believe the array is JSON - how is the best way for me to get access to that stuff to change it to HTML?

My whole array looks like this currently:

```
{"products":[{"id":8,"link":"http:\/\/www.mysite.com\/mydirectory\/prestashop\/trophies\/8-football-resin
.html","quantity":2,"image":"http:\/\/www.mysite.com\/mydirectory\/prestashop\/img\/p\/en-default-home_default
.jpg","image_cart":"http:\/\/www.mysite.com\/mydirectory\/prestashop\/img\/p\/en-default-cart_default
.jpg","priceByLine":"$40.00","name":"Football Resin","price":"$40.00","price_float":40,"idCombination"
:0,"idAddressDelivery":0,"is_gift":false,"hasAttributes":false,"hasCustomizedDatas":true,"customizedDatas"
:[{"customizationId":76,"quantity":1,"datas":[{"type":1,"datas":[{"index":0,"value":"%5B%5B%7B%22name
%22%3A%22trophy%5B1%5D%5Bline1%5D%22%2C%22engraving%22%3A%22ccc%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22trophy%5B1
%5D%5Bline2%5D%22%2C%22engraving%22%3A%22ddd%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22trophy%5B1%5D%5Bline3%5D%22%2C
%22engraving%22%3A%22dddd%22%7D%5D%5D","truncatedValue":"%5B%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22..."}]}]},{"customizationId"
:77,"quantity":1,"datas":[{"type":1,"datas":[{"index":0,"value":"%5B%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22trophy%5B1
%5D%5Bline1%5D%22%2C%22engraving%22%3A%22asdf%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22trophy%5B1%5D%5Bline2%5D%22
%2C%22engraving%22%3A%22dddasdf%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22trophy%5B1%5D%5Bline3%5D%22%2C%22engraving
%22%3A%22ddddddd%22%7D%5D%5D","truncatedValue":"%5B%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22..."}]}]}]}],"discounts":[]
,"shippingCost":"$7.00","shippingCostFloat":7,"wrappingCost":"$0.00","nbTotalProducts":2,"total":"$47
.00","productTotal":"$40.00","freeShipping":"$0.00","freeShippingFloat":0,"free_ship":false,"isVirtualCart"
:false,"hasError":false,"crossSelling":""}
```

The part I am interested in getting to is the 'value' in the customizedDatas (I formatted it that way so I could more easily read it):

```
"customizedDatas"
:
    [

    {
    "customizationId":76,
    "quantity":1,
    "datas":
        [{
            "type":1,
            "datas":
            [{
                "index":0,"value":"%5B%5B%7B%22name
                %22%3A%22trophy%5B1%5D%5Bline1%5D%22%2C%22engraving%22%3A%22ccc%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22trophy%5B1
                %5D%5Bline2%5D%22%2C%22engraving%22%3A%22ddd%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22trophy%5B1%5D%5Bline3%5D%22%2C
                %22engraving%22%3A%22dddd%22%7D%5D%5D","truncatedValue":"%5B%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22..."
            }]
        }]
    },
```

You can see the 'value' is a bunch of encoded/serialized JSON. I need to pull that from the array, convert the parts of it to HTML, then dump it back into the array and finish passing it to the view.

I have changed some parts on the front-end to do it, but there are numerous spots that call for this information - so I am trying to do it in the controller so it displays nicely everywhere instead of trying to update dozens of bits of code throughout the front end.

On the front end - this works:

```
{if isset($customization.datas.$CUSTOMIZE_TEXTFIELD.0)}
    {$encoded_values = $customization.datas.$CUSTOMIZE_TEXTFIELD.0.value}
    {$decoded_url_values = urldecode($encoded_values)}
    {$json_values = json_decode($decoded_url_values)}
    {$json_key_values=array_keys($json_values)}
    {foreach $json_values as $orderItems }
            <h6 class="item-cart-title">{l s='Item '}{$orderItems@index+1}</h6>
            <ul>
        {foreach $orderItems as $orderItem }
            <li class="item-cart-engraving">{l s='Line '}{$orderItem@index+1} : {$orderItem->engraving}</li>
        {/foreach}
            </ul>
    {/foreach}
```

How do I get to the data for the 'value' in the above array?

Currently the customizedDatas is built like this:

```
$customized_datas[(int)$row['id_product']][(int)$row['id_product_attribute']][(int)$row['id_address_delivery']][(int)$row['id_customization']]['datas'][(int)$row['type']][] = $row;
```

So I know ['datas'] is what I want - but what is the best way to access the objects inside of that array?

Comment: If you choose to downvote - please provide me with a reason why so I know if I've done something incorrectly.

Comment: The "array" you have posted is a JSON string.  Where is the PHP array you say it's stored in?

Comment: @Hanny I agree and upvoted just for that reason. Not sure I can help but checking out your code now.

Comment: `["products"][0]["customizedDatas"][0]["datas"][0]["datas"][0]["value"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said there's an array, but you've posted a string - with extraneous newlines that break the JSON format -so I'm not sure where your JSON actually is.  But assuming you can get properly-formatted JSON into a string, you can turn it into a PHP array with the `json_decode` function.

```
$data = json_decode($json_string_goes_here);
```

Then you just have a PHP array that you can access as you would any other. For example, maybe something like this:

```
foreach ($data['products'][0]['customizedDatas'] as $custom) {
  echo("Customization $custom[customizationId]:");
  foreach ($custom['datas'] as $datum) {  
    echo("Data type: $datum[type]");
    echo("Subdata:");
    print_r($datum['datas']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark.  This is the direction I needed to head in - I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your json array is not looking correctly. There is something incorrect in your array. If you josn array is fine then you can do it like this.

```
    $JSONdecodedarray = json_decode($yourJsonArray);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($JSONdecodedarray);
    echo "</pre>";
```

This way you can easily track your required index.

Comment: It's the line breaks/newlines. Delete them to get valid json.